# Assign Map<String, List<String>> input to Map<String, List<String>> output

Tags: java, stream

I'm new to Streams and I want something like this:
I have an input Map with `<String, List<String>>`. I want to read this map in a stream and assign it to an output map with `<String, String>` with the value being the first element of the value list from input map.
Example:

```
**Input:**
{key1, [value1 value2]}
{key2, null}

**Output**
{key1, value1}
{key2, null}
```

Notice, when the list in the first map is null, then it should be written as null in the second map. If the list is empty, then it should also write null in the second map value

What I have tried:

```
Map<String, String> output= input.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get(0)));
```

This gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when the list is empty in the first map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Collectors.toMap` will *also* throw if you put a `null` value in.

To get around this, you can in-line build a `Collector` for `Map`.  For example, something like:

```java
final Map<String, String> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new, // Create a Map if none is present
                (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), // Keys stay the same
                (entry.getValue() == null || entry.getValue().isEmpty()) // Check for empty
                    ? null : entry.getValue().iterator().next()), // Get first if present
                HashMap::putAll); // Combining function
```

Note: wrapping this with `Collections.unmodifiableMap` makes sense to avoid future contamination.
Note: Pulling out the 'get first value or null' to a method like the following is probably considerably more readable, and allows the combining bit to just become `this.getFirstIfPresent(entry.getValue())` in the above pipeline:

```java
private static <T> @Nullable T getFirstIfPresent(final List<T> input) {
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    return list.iterator().next();
}
```